# PHP Merge 2 Images (Insert Face To An Image)

Tags: php, image, merge, photo

I need your help

I have two images,
1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSt6q.jpg (face image, type: jpeg)
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9MNh.png (frame image, with hole in face, type: png)

I want insert face image into frame image

I tried this script

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('face.jpg');
$frame = imagecreatefrompng('ironman.png');

$iw = imagesx($image);
$ih = imagesy($image);

$fw = imagesx($frame);
$fh = imagesy($frame);

imagealphablending($frame, true);
imagesavealpha($frame, true);
imagecopy($image, $frame, 0, 0, 0, 0, $fw, $fh);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);

imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($frame);
?>
```

The problem are:
Resolution of result image doesn't same with resolution of frame image, and
How to change position of face image, so the face image can right on hole in frame image

Comment: This question is way too broad and shows a lack of documentation reading. Unfortunately I'm out of close votes :).

Comment: Hi user1450710, did you find the solution of this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can scale images to get the same resolutions. Here's the sample code for scaling:

```
function scale($scale){
    //you can get image width and height from image info
    $width = $image_width * $scale / 100;
    $height = $image_height * $scale / 100;

    $scaled_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($scaled_image, $old_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $image_width, $image_height);
}
```

To change position of **face image** you can set parameters you want in [`imagecopy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) function. You'll need to set `dst_x` and `dst_y`.